# Why file is not copied to bin folder in Visual Studio project?

Tags: visual-studio

I have log4net.config set as "Copy Always"

[image]

**But it is not being copied to Output folder at all.**

Why is that?

Comment: I know this is stupid but it happened to me once. Are you sure you're not using Release configuration and checking the Debug folder or vice-versa?

Comment: Nope, checking the right location